# How to return the index of an element in a list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, random, indexing

```
List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

i want to pick a random element in `List` and return the index of it.

when I do:

```
List.index(random.choice(List[random.randint(0,2)]))
```

it obviously gives me an error, because the code only indexes the list-elements in `List`.

what I would like to have is something like:

```
output: The random number is: 4 and the index is: (1,0) or List[1][0]
```

Comment: You've clearly found the flaw in your logic -- `4` is not in `List`. You need to iterate over the elements of `List` and find the one that contains `4`. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Since the element is chosen at random, why not do it the other way - choose random index to obtain a random element?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i postet a solution I found. I think you mean it like this?

Comment: @pjs that is actually True xD

Answer (score 1):

In the .index() section of python3.x list documentation you will see, index method returns "zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to search element". In your case all of the elements in the List are lists.
To get the index of list containing the search number and the it's position in that list you will have to do something like this:

```
List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
el = random.choice(List[random.randint(0,len(List))])
result = [(y, List[y].index(el)) for y, _ in enumerate(List) if (el in List[y])]
```

Comment: This works fine! what does the _ stand for in a loop? ... is it just a placeholder?

Comment: "_" is a placeholder for a throwaway variable.

Comment: Why discard the value returned by `enumerate()` and then index into `List`? Just do `for y, val in enumerate(List)` and then use `val` instead of `List[y]`.

Comment: I used List[y] instead of using the second variable of enumerate to stress that we are looking into the y-index of the List. Using .index() on val works as well. Thanks for the suggestion @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this. I don't know if its convenient or not. I feel like there should be a better solution xD

```
tuple = (0, 0)
num = random.choice(List[random.randint(0,2)])
for i in List:
    if num in i:
        print(f"the random number is {num} and the index is {List.index(i), i.index(num)}")

output: the random number is 9 and the index is (2, 2)
```

Comment: This is a great start! A few notes: 1. `tuple` already means something, so you probably want to name it something else to avoid shadowing the inbuilt `tuple` class. 2. Look into the `enumerate()` function -- this will let you iterate over a collection with the index and the value, so you won't need to call `List.index()` again. 3. `if num in i` needs to iterate over the entire list `i` to find if `num` exists in it. Then `i.index()` needs to do the same to find out where it is in the list. Instead, you could have another loop like the outer loop so that  this is done in one shot.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I found out about the enumerate() function rn after the comment of @ SaiKiran. I get it...I'll try your next hint. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the given List as 2-d array i.e matrix

```
import random
# Userinput rows = int(input());matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for ctr in range(rows)]
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
rowIndex = random.randint(0, len(matrix) - 1)
colIndex = random.randint(0, len(matrix[rowIndex]) - 1)
print(f"The random number is: {matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]} and the index is: {(rowIndex, colIndex)} or matrix[{rowIndex}][{colIndex}]")
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for any size list in `List`, not just size 3.

```
import random

List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

rand1 = random.randint(0, len(List)-1)
rand2 = random.randint(0, len(List[rand1]-1))

print("The random number is: {} and the index is: {}".format(List[rand1][rand2], (rand1, rand2)))
```

Output: `The random number is: 6 and the index is: (1, 2)`